# RewriteRules in .htaccess in subdirectory disabling/breaking RewriteRules in .htaccess in parent directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd, drupal

This is a shared hosting account with HostGator.

I've two `.htaccess` files.

One is in the document root: `~/public_html/.htaccess`

```
# this is ~/public_html/.htaccess
## Redirect to https:// ##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/~myusername/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The other is in a subdirectory: `~/public_html/software/drupal-7.0/.htaccess`. The contents  of this `.htaccess` file can be found [in the Drupal git](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob_plain/497914920385b7016ac9c9367e0198530787adf2:/.htaccess).

The function of the `.htaccess` in the web root is to redirect all requests to `https://`. This works when I visit any URL except for those which are served from `~/public_html/software/drupal-7.0/`.

I want my `https://` redirection to work in `~/public_html/software/drupal-7.0/`, as well, without modifying the `.htaccess` file which is in this directory.

Moving `~/public_html/software/drupal-7.0/.htaccess` some place else seems to allow the `https://` redirection to occur.

Why isn't my redirection occurring in URLs which are served from `~/public_html/software/drupal-7.0/`, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteOptions Inherit` in the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file would cause the rules in the subdir to be evaluated, then the rules in the parent context.

If the Drupal rules make any changes, since this is per-directory context they will be sent back through the process a 2nd time and on the 2nd pass the canonical hostname rewrites will take effect.

Comment: The combination of directories not inheriting rewrite rules by default and the necessity of the directive which enables inheritance to be in the child and not the parent means that I have to modify the .htaccess file supplied by Drupal. It is meant to be edited, though, so I guess that this is OK.

Comment: An added complication with mod_rewrite inheritance is that the directives are effectively copied in-place into the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file. This means that the directives might not even work the same as when used in the parent directory - which is the case with the HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the question. These directives are unlikely to work without modification, due to the capturing backreference from the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. The use of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable might be required instead. There are now more "inheritance" options available with Apache 2.4.